# I only have AMD Radeon Settings Lite in my laptop

Tags: gpu, amd-processor

As I said in the subject, I only got AMD Radeon Settings Lite in my device. Which makes me wonder, isn't the Lite version only provides a certain amount of settings that you can tweak? When I go research on the internet on how to settings the graphic card for gaming, I've found out that my AMD Radeon Settings Lite have limited amount of setting that can be justified. Should I go download the non-Lite version online or what?

Comment: If you want help writing a computer program, we can provide that, but general computer usage is off topic here.

Comment: did you update amd adrenaline? I had amd settings lite and a couple of weeks ago I installed Adrenaline... It just screwed up my computer. Coming back to the lite version, for sure.